# laravel app before session

Tags: session, laravel

I'm using php laravel framework, I want to set the prefix of route group by session:

```
App::before(function(){
    Session::put('lang', Request::segment(1));
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => Session::get('lang')), function(){
    //home
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'IndexController@index'));
    //login
    Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UserController@login'));
    Route::post('/do-login', array('as' => 'do_login', 'uses' => 'UserController@doLogin'));
    Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UserController@logout'));
});
```

The default url of login is: localhost:9090/en/login. But if I change 'en' to 'zh'(or something else) the application threw 'Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException' exception. 
I then refresh the changed url(localhost:9090/zh/login), the page shows correctly.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: It seems like what you really need is a way to exclude the language part of the URL from the routing altogether, so your routes behave the same regardless of the language selected - is that correct?

Comment: Actually, I am confused that why cann't get the session value. It is strange that if I run "die(Session::get('lang'))" in 'App::before' closuer function, it can get the correct session value at the first time I refresh the page.

Comment: Well that's not what your question implies - your question seems to be that you want to know how to make the routes work with the language codes preceeding the routes.